# Como customizar rotas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho um controller chamado login e uma view do mesmo nome. Quando eu acesso a pagina de login, a URL é exibida dessa forma: `~/Login/Login`

É possível customizar essa rota, para que o link fique assim: `~/Login`?

Answer (score 1):

Nesta **controller** `Login` existe alguma `Action` ? Dá uma olhada no seu **Global.asax** e vê como está a rota padrão tem que estar assim:

```
IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
      "Default", // Padrão 
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // Parametros da URL
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 

);
```

Mas neste você pode colocar assim:

```
new { controller = "Login", action = "NomeDaActionDentroDaControllerLogin", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Junto com tudo, desta forma:

```
"Default", // Padrão 
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // Parametros da URL
   new { controller = "Login", action = "NomeDaActionDentroDaControllerLogin", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Não tem problema ter uma **`View`** como o mesmo nome da **Controller**, mas veja como está a rota **padrão** neste arquivo **Global.asax**. E coloca da forma que coloquei aqui, e também verifique como esta rota está sendo chamada por exemplo, se você está via localhost, deve aparecer da forma padrão como na rota:

```
http://localhost:2020/Controller/Action/Id=?....!
```

Se alguma **Action** dentro da **LoginController** no seu projeto, chamar está **`View Login`** com o mesmo nome, na URL só deve ser chamado assim

```
http://localhost:2020/Controller/Action/
```

Não se chama a **`View`**, chama-se a **Action**.E então a **Action** vai renderizar para a **`View`** que você criou dentro dela !